# Assignment doesn't work but address of with the dereference operator does?

Tags: c++, file, c++11, variables, dereference

I've been playing around with C++ (just starting out), and I'm trying to make a program that needs a function to count the lines in C++. However, I've encountered weird behavior where normal assignment doesn't work, but assignment through address of, and then immediate dereference does. Like this:

```
int countLinesInFile(string fileName){
  char c[32];
  int numLines = 0;
  ifstream file(fileName);

  while(file >> c){
    numLines += 1;
    cout << "Lines: " << numLines << endl;
  }
  return numLines;
}
```

Which results in:

```
Lines: 1
Lines: 1
Lines: 1
Lines: 1
Lines: 1
Lines: 1
```

However, when I change `numLines += 1` to `*(&numLines) += 1` it magically works:

```
Lines: 1
Lines: 2
Lines: 3
Lines: 4
Lines: 5
Lines: 6
```

For a little background, the file I'm reading is a 6 line file where each line is a 32 bit binary string (equal to zero). When I print out c (with `cout << c`) it prints out seemingly correctly. Also, I am aware that this may not be the optimal or correct way of doing read lines from a file, but unless this simply can not possibly work, I am more interested in the underlying mechanics of why this behavior is happening, and what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why are you using raw arrays with c++ (supposedly even c++11) code?

Comment: Could you explain why this is a problem, or a least give me a keyword to search for?

Comment: Ensure that `ifstream file(fileName);` was opened correctly.

Comment: Use `std::string` and `getline`!

Comment: 32 characters in each line of the file? Well, then you need a 33 character buffer. Otherwise, where is the nul terminating character gonna go? You have undefined behavior in your program.

Comment: Typical StackOverflow. 6 comments and nobody even trying to answer the question. Well that's 7 now.

Comment: @StoryTeller That probably is the issue, since I can't seem to reproduce the error with lines that are less than [32 characters long](https://repl.it/repls/PaltryMellowBot).

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois Well, questions like mine turn out to be substantial, lead beyond and discover serious design flaws beforehand. I don't see what's bad or unconstructive with this. We should capture such misconceptions at their roots.

Comment: Are you really sure the line counter doesn't get incremented?! I think it gets incremented however the result is incorrect.

Comment: Ahhhh. The magic of undefined behaviour. Sometimes it is visibly wrong and sometimes it isn't. Sometimes it even looks right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'\0'` character binary value is `00000000`. I guess that `numLines` is just after your array `c` in memory and is always erased with zeros, before being incremented by 1. So it always displays as 1.

When you compile the second version, the memory must be organized another way (only the compiler knows, and you if you debug at very low level), which does not impact `numLines` value.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's the answer. As *StoryTeller* said, the array must be 33 characters long in order to capture the terminating character and prevent the unusual behavior.

P.S. Thank you for all the helpful comments, and I agree that getline is probably a better alternative. If anyone has any insight as to how exactly this overflow might cause this weird behavior that would be very welcome.

Comment: The least significant byte of `numLines` is probably stored in memory where `c[32]` would be if it existed.  Thus, `numLines` is being overwritten by the `'\0'` character in every iteration of the loop.  Using `*(&numLines)` causes the compiler to lay the stack out slightly differently (it needs space for an extra pointer), causing `numLines` not to get overwritten.  It's likely you will get different results with different optimization flags.

Answer (score 0):

Use class `std::string` with the API `std::getline` where you can read a whole line at each read and increment at each read the counter variable:

```
std::string sLine;
std::ifstream in("main.cpp");
int nLines = 0;

while(std::getline(in, sLine))
    ++nLines;
std::cout << nLines << endl;

in.close();
```

Comment: While this is a useful idea, this doesn't really answer what is wrong with OP's code, and why his first approach didn't work while his second did.